# How do I rotate the order of individual images when clicked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, parent-child

I need to display 3 animal pictures “Cat”, “Dog” and “Frog” in this order.
Whenever the user clicks the “Cat” picture, an alert window appears saying “Don’t click me,
click the frog”.
Whenever the user clicks the “Dog” picture, an alert window appears saying “Don’t click me,
click the frog”.
Whenever the user clicks the “Frog” picture, the frog will jump over the cat and dog. It means
that in the beginning it shows Cat Dog Frog, when the user clicks the frog then it becomes Frog
Cat Dog, the user clicks the frog again then it becomes Cat Dog Frog, etc.

Edit: The pictures need to be horizontal but I currently have them vertical. I can't seem to figure out how to make them horizontal.
Here's my code so far:

```js
function swapDiv(event,elem){
    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem,elem.parentNode.firstChild);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <td><div onclick="swapDiv(event,this);"><img src="cat.png" 
    style="width:200;height:200;"/></div></td>
    <td><div onclick="swapDiv(event,this);"><img src="dog.png" 
    style="width:175;height:175;"/></div></td>
    <td><div onclick="swapDiv(event,this);"><img src="frog.png" 
    style="width:150;height:150;"/></div></td>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the images in a single line, you need to give your `div`'s within your `#container` div a `display` of `inline` in your CSS like so:

```
#container > div {
  display: inline;
}
```

Next, as your images need to display an alert when the frog is not clicked, you can add a separate function which will create the `alert` popup. Then, you can set the `onclick` for the cat and dog to execute this function.

To make the frog jump from left to right, you can create a global variable in your javascript. In the example below I called it `frogJumped`. This variable keeps track of whether or not the frog has jumped. Initially, it is `false` as the frog hasn't jumped yet. Then, in your `swapDiv` method you can check if the frog has jumped using an `if` statement. If the frog has jumped, you'll need to move the div after the `lastNode` of the parent. If the frog hasn't jumped you'll need to move it to be `firstChild` of your `container` div. Finally, you can use `frogJumped = !frogJumped` to set the boolean to be the opposite of what it currently was. This way you can update the frog's jump status every time you click it.

See example below:

```js
let frogJumped = false; // Keep track of the side the frog is on

function clickFrog() { // Create a function to execute when a non-frog image is clicked
  alert("Don't click me, click the frog"); // create the alert window
}

function swapDiv(event, elem) {
  if(frogJumped) { // Check if the frog has jumped, if it has, move it back to its original position
    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, elem.parentNode.lastChild);
  } else { // If the frog hasn't jumped, move it to the left of all the images
   elem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, elem.parentNode.firstChild);
  }
  frogJumped = !frogJumped; // Set true -> false, and false -> true
}
```

```css
#container > div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <td>
    <div onclick="clickFrog();"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="width:200px;height:200px;" /></div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div onclick="clickFrog();"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518020382113-a7e8fc38eac9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="width:175px;height:175px;" /></div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div onclick="swapDiv(event,this);"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506506447188-78e2a1051d9e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="width:150px;height:150px;" /></div>
  </td>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach but inspired by Nick's answer:

```js
function clickFrog() { // Create a function to execute when a non-frog image is clicked
  alert("Don't click me, click the frog"); // create the alert window
}

function swapDiv(e, o) {
  o.classList.toggle("jumped");
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

.jumped {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <td>
    <div onclick="clickFrog();"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="width:200px;height:200px;" /></div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div onclick="clickFrog();"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518020382113-a7e8fc38eac9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="width:175px;height:175px;" /></div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div onclick="swapDiv(event,this);"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506506447188-78e2a1051d9e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="width:150px;height:150px;" /></div>
  </td>
</div>
```